# When to use the -g flag to GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to force ValGrind to tell me what's wrong with my program. Every shred of documentation on the face of the Internet says that you must supply the `-g` option to GCC, but not one single document says whether you need this flag at *compile-time* or *link-time* (or both). So which is it??

Comment: `-g` is a compiler option not a linker option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU ld documentation says that `-g` will be ignored, so it doesn't make much sense to pass it. In general you pass `-g` to `gcc` (which really is a front-end for the whole compilation process and not just a compiler) and it will take care of it.

Comment: To be 100% clear: You are saying that `-g` is required at _compile-time_ and is not needed at _link-time_?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, see `man ld` if you have any doubts.  It'd tell you that `-g` is provided for _compatibility with other tools_.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

GCC provides -g flag to get the debugging, So one you compile the program like
Consider a code of example.c like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* Warning: This program is wrong on purpose. */
int main()
{
int age = 10;
int height;
printf("I am %d years old.\n");
printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);
return 0;
}
```

By default if you compile say using `make example`
It will trigger command

```
cc     example.c   -o example
```

Now you run command like

```
cc -g example.c -o example1
```

then you will find the `size of the file example1` is greater than the `size of example`
because -g flag enabled the debugging information.

While running valgrind is -g flag is not required. -g is only required in compilation process.